# Javascript prototype Class Literals best practice

Tags: javascript, prototype, literals

I am new to Javascript, so I wonder if the following code is a good practice.

```
CustomClass = function(var1, var2) {
    this.var1 = var1;
    this.var2 = var2;
};
CustomClass.prototype.aMethod = function() {
    console.log("my class method");
};

// Intend as main .js object, if that makes sense
var m = {
    object1:CustomClass.prototype,
    object2:CustomClass.prototype,

    initObjects:function() {
        m.object1 = new CustomClass( value1, value2 );
        m.object1.aMethod();
        m.object2 = new CustomClass( value1, value2 );
        m.object2.aMethod();
    }
};
```

Or should I create my custom class inside the "s" literal?

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your actual code:

```
// globally scoped. Only avoided with closures and hoisting as shown below
// Also doesn't really make sense to define CustomClass on m unless you want
// To use it directly instead of through a factory function
CustomClass = function(var1, var2) {
    this.var1 = var1;
    this.var2 = var2;
};
CustomClass.prototype.aMethod = function() {
    console.log("my class method");
};

// Intend as main .js object, if that makes sense
var m = {
    // No reason to initialise them to the prototype. Doesn't really make sense
    // m can be edited without needing to intialise object1 or object2 at all
    object1:CustomClass.prototype,
    object2:CustomClass.prototype,

    initObjects:function() {
        m.object1 = new CustomClass( value1, value2 );
        m.object1.aMethod();
        m.object2 = new CustomClass( value1, value2 );
        m.object2.aMethod();
    }
};
```

A different pattern that might be of use based more on closures and hoisting. This takes a more functional approach and moves away from standard classical inheritance.

```
// Create closure to localise scope.
(function() {
    // global object to store anything that will be hoisted to global scope
    var global = {};

    // Constructor that uses local objects and defines methods on
    // this directly.
    var CustomClass = function(_a,_b) {
         var a = _a;
         var b = _b;

         this.method = function() { console.log("foo"); }
    }

    // init function will be hoisted to global scope.
    global.init = function() {
         global.object1 = new CustomClass( v1, v2 );
         object1.method();
         global.object2 = new CustomClass( v1, v2 );
         object2.method();
    }

    // Hoist you global object into the global variable "m" on window.
    window.m = global;
}());
```

Of course you lose the prototype chain so your must use a lot more object composition instead of object inheritance and this is also slower by a small amount. The loss of speed is only really noticable if your creating 1000+ objects

Comment: I'm afraid that v1 and v2 are undefined in your answer.